# How do I install Gournal?

Tags: 11.04, installation, dependencies, perl

I am trying to install [Gournal](http://www.adebenham.com/old-stuff/gournal/) and I can't because of a missing dependency which [doesn't appear to be in natty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&keywords=libgnome2-print-perl)?

```
gournal : Depends: libgnome2-print-perl but it is not installable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gournal looks like it stopped development in 2005 - thus the dependency in your question cannot be satisfied by the Natty packages.

As such, you will need to download the source package (the .tar file) and extract it.

In the folder you will see `install` - run this in a terminal

```
sudo ./install
```

This will install the perl `gournal` packages.

However the application still will not start without the `gnome2::print` perl module.

You could install this from CPAN - my brief experiment with this threw-up lots of compilation issues - but the application did start.  Just dont press the "print" button.  My guess is this section in `gournal` will need to be rewritten/updated to use newer supported perl print routines.

**pre-requisites**

```
sudo apt-get install libextutils-depends-perl libextutils-pkgconfig-perl libgnomeprintui2.2-dev libgtk2-gladexml-perl libgnome2-canvas-perl libxml-mini-perl
```

**install missing perl module**

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install Gnome2::Print'
```

Now start the application by running `gournal`:

[image]

Comment: I didn't know Gournal was discontinued, installed xournal instead